# Remove the remote head from `git branch -a` output

Tags: git

While running git branch -a , I am getting out put like the below

```
+ git branch -a
* development
  remotes/origin/AWS-MIGRATION
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/development
  remotes/origin/RMR-2809
```

I want to remove the   `remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/development`
I want to see only pure branch names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
git remote set-head origin --delete
```

This will delete the `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` name; `git branch -r` shortens it to `origin/HEAD` and `git branch -a` shortens in to `remotes/origin/HEAD`, so this is the name you want to get rid of.

Note that this name may come back, or not, depending on various other operations you run (including another `git remote set-head`).  The `remotes/origin/*` names you see here are not really *branch* names, but rather *remote-tracking names*.  Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names* and shows them under `-r` or `-a` output, but not under `git branch` output.

(In my opinion, there's no really good reason to delete the name, but there's no particularly good reason to keep it either.)

If you're writing *programs* that deal with branch names, do not use `git branch` to generate the list of names: this is the wrong tool.  (It's what Git calls *porcelain*, i.e., a tool mean to produce output read by a human.  Git's *plumbing* tools produce output meant to be read by other programs.)

Comment: I resolved it using shell script, "sed", but your option is better